# Let $w = \log(u^{2} + v^{2})$ where $u=e^{(x^{2}+y)}$ and $v= e^{(x+y^{2})}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Then $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$ for $(x=0,y=0)$ is ?
I got answer as 0 since on partial differentiation I got, $\frac{(4x^{3}+4xy).e^{(x^{2}+y)^2}+(2y^{2}+2x).e^{(y^{2}+x)^2}}{log(e^{(y^{2}+x)^2}+e^{(x^{2}+y)^2})}$

Comment: One of your mistakes :  $u^2\neq e^{(x^2+y)^2}$ but $u^2=e^{2(x^2+y)}$

Comment: Another mistake: $(\log z)'=\frac{z'}{z}$, not $\frac{z'}{\log z}$.

Comment: Ya I got my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Try rechecking your work.  The derivative of $\ln(f(x))$ is $f'/f$ .   Observe
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}= \frac{2 u \frac{\partial u }{\partial x  }+2v\frac{\partial v }{\partial x} } {u^2 + v^2} $$
where $\frac{\partial u }{\partial x} = e^{x^2 +y} (2x)$

and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = e^{x + y^2}$

When $(x,y) = 0$ we have that $u = 1$, $v = 1$, $\frac{\partial u }{\partial x} = 0$
and $\frac{\partial v }{\partial x} =1$.  Thus

$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=1$